# How to check on if statement if the current time is greater than the times

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a difficult with my code as I am trying to get pass on the if statement that when my current time `EPG_Now` is greater than the `EPG_Now` time.

Example: My current time show `12:38AM` is no greater than `12:55AM` so it would not get pass on the if statement unless my current time goes after `12:55AM`.

When I try this:

```
EPG_Time = time.strptime('07/10/2017 12:32AM', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p')
self.EPG_Now = ['06/10/2017 11:55AM']
self.EPG_Next = ['07/10/2017 12:55AM']

for EPG_Now, EPG_Next in zip(self.EPG_Now, self.EPG_Next):
    EPG_Now_time = time.strptime(EPG_Now, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p')
    EPG_Next_time = time.strptime(EPG_Next, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p

    if EPG_Time > EPG_Next_time:
       print "it is time to delete the data from the list......................."
```

It will always let me to get pass on the if statement when my current time is no greater than the `EPG_Now` which is wrong. I want to get pass on the if statement only when my current time is greater than `EPG_Now` time then I want to do something to delete from the list.

Can you please show me an example how I could get pass on the if statement that if my current time is greater than the `EPG_Now` time?

Comment: You should be using `datetime`, not `time`.

Comment: Oh thank you, can you post an example of what i should use?

Comment: Should I use something is like thi `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time))`?

Comment: `datetime` has a strptime function just like `time` does

Comment: can you please show me the code as I really want to see it what it will be like? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is over-complicating a simple issue.  Try this:

```
>>> EPG_Time = time.strptime('07/10/2017 12:32AM', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p')
>>> print EPG_Time
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=12, tm_min=32, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=280, tm_isdst=-1)

>>> EPG_Now = time.strptime('06/10/2017 11:55AM', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p')
>>> print EPG_Now
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=6, tm_hour=11, tm_min=55, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=279, tm_isdst=-1)

>>> EPG_Next = time.strptime('07/10/2017 12:55AM', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p')
>>> print EPG_Next
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=12, tm_min=55, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=280, tm_isdst=-1)

>>> EPG_Time > EPG_Next
False
```

This works exactly as expected. I don't think you've pasted in the code you're actually running -- you are missing a `')` on line 7. Maybe your code is out of synch with your original question.

Comment: Can you please post the code of what I should use instead of mine?

Answer (score 0):

The following might help if you fix the string representation of time:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Assume you have a list of datetime strings
#     Format: year-month-day-hour-minute-second
time_strs = ['2017-03-17-10-31-05', '2017-02-17-10-50-25']

# Extract each datetime unit and convert to ints
time_units = [[int(v) for v in dt.split("-")] for dt in time_strs]

# Create datetime objects from those units
time_objs = [datetime(*units) for units in time_units]

# You can now compare
if time_objs[1] > time_objs[0]:
    print(time_strs[1], " > ", time_strs[0])
else:
    print(time_strs[1], " < ", time_strs[0])
```

If you can store time at different checkpoints and work with those values, you should use datetime as suggested by others. An example:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

past = datetime.now()

# Assume you slept for 10 seconds
time.sleep(10)

present = datetime.now()

if past < present:
    print("That's how time works!")
```

Comment: as you have input `2017-03-17-10-31-05', '2017-02-17-10-50-25` so I dont know where to find to change the hours and mins as this is seen to be a mess